# Login and lock screen overlaping

Tags: gnome, themes

I am in Ubuntu 18.04 and when changing the login screen background editing the ubuntu.css file and when i log in the login screen and the lock screen with the clock overlapps and every time i press a key it stutters and sometimes after i put my password for a few seconds i can use the computer and then it goes to black and i have to press the power button to light up the screen again.

The changes i made to the file are this:

lockDialogGroup {

background: #2c001e url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);

background-repeat: repeat;

}

to this:

lockDialogGroup 
{

background: #2c001e url("CUSTOM PATH");

background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-size: cover;

background-position: center;

}

and this is the source : https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-change-gdm-login-screen-background-in-ubuntu/

[image: Login Screen]